# Microsoft Excel 2010 Stacked Bar chart with multiple series

Tags: excel

[image]

I have a table with Countries vs Series names (A1,A2.. etc as shown in image). 
For Ex: For India the series names are A1,A2,A3,A4. For Japan the Series names are B1,B2,B3,B4 and for USA the series names are C1,C2,C3,C4. 
How can i have these series names labels along side the values for particular location data in the stacked bar chart. For ex: For India Bar chart i should have (A1,200) (A2,200) (A3,200) (A4,300) and for Japan (B1,200)(B2,300),(B3,400),(B4,200) and similarly for USA in the stacked bar chart.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to add series name adjacent to the values